# capacitor in schematic without unit

Tags: schematics

Can you help me identify the correct values of the marked capacitors? And what are the values between the brackets?

As a bonus question: What is the purpose of this transistors?
The schematics show a one line UART with 13V, 500 boud. The upper part is the receiving part, the lower for sending.

Thank you.

[image: schematics with unknown capacitor values]

Comment: Based on context the most likely units are microfarads.

Comment: The transistor Q303 is a prebiased NPN having 4.7K resistors. The data sheet says applications would include inverter, interface, driver. My guess is inverter.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely:
0.01 = 10nF
0.1 = 100nF

C304 is a decoupling cap. 100nF is very common value. C309 forms low pass filter with R330.

Answer (score 2):

Capacitor values are usually given in microfarads, unless otherwise indicated.

Those capacitors are 0.1 uF and 0.01 uF (or 100 nF and 10 nF).

I don't know what the `<B>` and `<F>`  mean - perhaps there's a note somewhere on the schematic or in the parts list stating what they mean...

Answer (score 0):

C310 is shown as 1000p. As pointed out in a previous answer, capacitor values are usually given in microfarads unless otherwise indicated.  In this case, the p is meant to designate the units as picofarads so C310 is 1000 pF.